# Elastic Beanstalk - running npm install and webpack on every deployment of Django

Tags: django, webpack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to use Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my Django server.

My problem is that part of my deployment process is to "npm install" from my package.json, and then executing webpack (`npx webpack ..... --output main.js`)

How can I do that while maintaining an easy deployment process (`eb deploy`) and without committing `main.js` to the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it, you'll probably need `ebextensions` to configure your Elastic Beanstalk environment. Documentation is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html).

I recently deploy my Symfony app on ElasticBeanstalk which needed Yarn to execute webpack.

To do it, I created a `.config` file in which I write the commands to install Yarn and another `.config` file to run Yarn at each deployment. All `.config` files are in `.ebextensions` directory at the root of the project.

```
commands:
  01_install_node:
    command: |
      sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -
      sudo yum -y install nodejs 
  02_install_yarn:
    command: |
      sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
      sudo yum -y install yarn
```

> You can use the container_commands key to execute commands that affect
>   your application source code. Container commands run after the
>   application and web server have been set up and the application
>   version archive has been extracted.

```
container_commands:
  02_run_yarn:
    command: |
      yarn install
      yarn run encore production
```